# Markes dump displays nulls for IMarker.LINE_NUMBER and IMarker.CHAR_START Plugin development markers

Tags: eclipse, plugins, markers

I have following generic code that dumps all the markers with all the attibutes in the system. If I set some breakpoints the value for both LINE_NUMBER and IMarker.CHAR_START is always displaed as null despite them having a clear value.
Can Anybody help understand that?

```
private void printAllMarkers() {
        IMarker[] markers = null;
        IWorkspace root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
        IProject projects[] = root.getRoot().getProjects();
        for (IProject p : projects) {
            try {
                markers = p.findMarkers(IMarker.MARKER, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
                System.out.println("\nAll Markers Are: ");
                for (IMarker m : markers) {
                    System.out.println("-----------Marker of Type: " + m.getType());
                    dumpMarker(m);
                }
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    public static void dumpMarker(IMarker m) {
        try {
            for (String attrName : m.getAttributes().keySet()) {
                System.out.println("Attribute:" + attrName + "=" + m.getAttribute(attrName, null));
            }
        } catch (CoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It's an Eclipse bug that displays the value as null if it comes from a 'supertype"
so getAttribute(attrName, null) will return null for lineStart even if the attribute exists.